# I Can't change the Button's color onClick in Android Studio by Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I can't change the button color when I pressed on it after using onClick event, it still has the same color. the kotlin code below..

```
fun buttonSelect(view:View){
    val buSelect=view as Button
    var cellID=0

    when(buSelect.id){
        R.id.bu11 -> cellID=1
        R.id.bu12 -> cellID=2
        R.id.bu13 -> cellID=3
        R.id.bu21 -> cellID=4
        R.id.bu22 -> cellID=5
        R.id.bu23 -> cellID=6
        R.id.bu31 -> cellID=7
        R.id.bu32 -> cellID=8
        R.id.bu33 -> cellID=9
    }
    Log.d("Cell id: ",cellID.toString())
    buSelect.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black)
}
```

}

Comment: what's with the `**`? That's not valid syntax, is it?

Comment: because you are always setting the color of this button "buSelect" only

Comment: where and how is this `buttonSelect` called? and the id selection seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Please provide the XML code, and explain what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use onClickListener

```
myButton.setOnClickListener {
    myButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black)
}
```